# Get "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'garnett'" in command line, despite working in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, command-line, jupyter-notebook, conda

I installed a package called garnett in my Anaconda environment using `conda install -c conda-forge garnett -n env` However, when I run `py script.py`, which uses garnett, I get the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'garnett'` on the line that imports the package. In Jupyter Notebook, in the same Conda environment in the same directory, it works just fine; it only started malfunctioning when I converted that Jupyter Notebook to a py file and tried running it from the command line. How can I try fixing this?

Edit: My Python version was too recent and had to be downgraded to 3.7.9, since freud doesn't support newer versions. The Python running on my Jupyter Notebook was already at 3.7.9, but not the Python running on my command line. This solved the problem.

Comment: take a look at 1) the python interpreters and 2) the values of `sys.path`. Are they the same?

Comment: @MZ After some research, I think I found my sys.path: ['', 'C:\\Python38\\python38.zip', 'C:\\Python38\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python38\\lib', 'C:\\Python38', 'C:\\Users\\caleb\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python38\\site-packages', 'C:\\Python38\\lib\\site-packages'] My Python version is 3.8.5; is that what you mean? If the "Python38" that shows up in most of those pathnames means Python 3.8.*, then I guess they're sort of the same...

Comment: is that the same in cmd line as it is in your jupyter notebook